# RedirectToAction returns to calling Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Inside my Index action I call my NotFound Action.  I follow in debug and the if condition tests true, it goes to the "return RedirectToAction("NotFound");" statement, it then goes to Dispose and then returns to the Index Action not the NotFound Action.  If I Redirect to the Details Action it works fine.  These are all in the same controller.  The NotFound View just contains text.

```
if (condition tests true) { return RedirectToAction("NotFound"); } 

public ActionResult NotFound()
{ return View(); }
```

I've also tried the NotFound as a ViewResult. It still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `NotFound` View directly from your Index action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{      
  if(yourcondition)
  {
     return View("NotFound");
  }
  else
  {
     // Return the Index View.
     return View();
  }  
}
```

This will work as long as there is a view named "NotFound.cshtml"

Comment: @Joe, As per your description, it should work, but without seeing the code, i can not say much, by the way where is this Dispose method coming from ?

Comment: It is generated by the Controller template.    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      _db.Dispose();
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }      I cannot figure out why I can not create a new Action in the controller.  If I duplicate the Details Action and rename it to Details2 it works.  If I slowly change it it stops working when I change the name of a parameter I pass it??????  Your code is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do.  The rest remains a mystery.